# Why spring boot dependency spring-boot-starter-validation is missing

Tags: java, spring, dependencies

I am creating my first microservice in Spring and I would like to add dependency spring-boot-starter-validation into my pom.xml, but I have errors that this dependency does not exist.

I am using java version 17, model Version: 4.0.0 and version of parent 3.1.5

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

the errors I getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEp9j.jpg

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>library</name>
    <description>my first microservice - REST API library</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am just trying to google I am new to non-university programming, so I would love to get some help. Thank you very much

Comment: could you please add more `pom.xml` to the question?

Comment: I added it into text

Comment: try removing `.idea` folder after closing the project. Roughly speaking, try re-initializing the project. Also, do you use public M2 repository?

Comment: removing .idea helped. Thank you so much. And I have no idea honestly - I guess so from what I read